# Can i render dynamic content and use a template engine (ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, templating

I am building weather app as a way to practice using express & ejs. 
I'm using app.get to request info from darkSky's API.
This call is being made once and it is successful, I'm also able to render it in my index.ejs file.

I would like to add a real time clock feature using moment.js that is called using setInterval. (it is the commented out function 'updateTime()')

Since I do not want to recall the weather API each time the clock would be updated, I think it needs to be outside of the app.get call.

I'm not sure how to set this up, because it seems like I cannot use DOM manipulation to add the clock feature in.

Is there a way get dynamic content in my ejs, that is separate from my API call?

(ps - the code snippet won't run, I just wanted to add the code in for a point of refrence)

```js
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request')
const moment = require('moment')

const app = express();
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public')

app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

let sush = 'e20fe780791cad1d4d4d7b8484f970a5';
let lat = 39.892692;
let lng = -86.290568;

let apiUrl = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${sush}/${lat},${lng}`;

// function updateTime() {
//     let dayTime = moment().format("dddd h:mma")
//     console.log(dayTime)
//  }
//  setInterval(updateTime, 5000)

// app.use("/", function (req, res){
    let dayTime;
    function updateTime() {
        dayTime = moment().format("dddd h:mma")
        console.log(dayTime)
        return dayTime
     }
     setInterval(updateTime, 5000)
    //  res.render('index.ejs', {dayTime:dayTime})
// })

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    request(apiUrl, function (error, response, body) {

        if (error){
            console.log('hey, hi, i didnt work - am i internet?')
        } 
        
        weather_json = JSON.parse(body);

        let dataDayThree = weather_json.daily.data[2].time;
        let dataDayFour = weather_json.daily.data[3].time;
        let dataDayFive = weather_json.daily.data[4].time

        let daytwo = moment.unix(weather_json.daily.data[1].time).format("dddd")
        let daythree = moment.unix(dataDayThree).format("dddd")
        let dayfour = moment.unix(dataDayFour).format("dddd")
        let dayfive = moment.unix(dataDayFive).format("dddd")

        let iconCurrentlyOut = weather_json.currently.icon;
        let iconTodayOut = weather_json.daily.data[0].icon;
        let iconTomorrowOut = weather_json.daily.data[1].icon;
        let iconDay3Out = weather_json.daily.data[2].icon;
        let iconDay4Out = weather_json.daily.data[3].icon;
        let iconDay5Out = weather_json.daily.data[4].icon;

        function iconLooper(x){

            switch (x) {
                case 'rain':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--lV_oG1pX--/v1515194565/rainy-6_pzlrlc.svg";
                    break;
                case 'snow':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--EsqjgOhi--/v1515194606/snowy-6_zl9kwx.svg";
                    break;
                case 'clear-day':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s---6vDoixr--/v1515194528/day_shry4k.svg";
                    break;
                case 'clear-night':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--CxSp0zXi--/v1515194530/night_quuh8p.svg";
                    break;
                case 'sleet':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--yeTLFcMd--/v1515194570/rainy-7_sdbkyl.svg";
                    break;
                case 'wind':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--ivgWegRI--/v1515194500/cloudy_vqbnvk.svg"
                    break;
                case 'fog':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--ivgWegRI--/v1515194500/cloudy_vqbnvk.svg"
                    break;
                case 'cloudy':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--ivgWegRI--/v1515194500/cloudy_vqbnvk.svg";
                    break;
                case 'partly-cloudy-day':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--pkzBuC_i--/v1515194500/cloudy-day-1_n3vykl.svg";
                    break;
                case 'snow':
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--DdrT7Iph--/v1515194500/cloudy-night-1_ro8fb5.svg";
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('i dont know whats goin on')    
                    iconCurrently = "https://res.cloudinary.com/raphaeladdile/image/upload/s--ivgWegRI--/v1515194500/cloudy_vqbnvk.svg";
                    defaultTest = "i am an unkno"
            }
            return iconCurrently
        }

          ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         // if default in switch is activated add in what the actual weather is, like 'thunderstorms' //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // function updateTime() {
        //     dayTime = moment().format("dddd h:mma")
        //     console.log(dayTime)
        //     return dayTime
        //  }
        //  setInterval(updateTime, 5000)

        let weather = {
            // date & time
            //dayTime: updateTime(),
            date: moment().format("MMM Do. YYYY"),
            // current
            currentTemp: Math.round(weather_json.currently.temperature),
            summary: weather_json.currently.summary,
            currentIcon: iconLooper(iconCurrentlyOut),
            currentFeelLike: Math.round(weather_json.currently.apparentTemperature),
            currentHumidity: Math.round(100 * (weather_json.currently.humidity)),
            dailySummary: weather_json.daily.summary,
            todayHi: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[0].temperatureMax),
            todayLo: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[0].temperatureMin),
            todayIcon: iconLooper(iconTodayOut),
            // tomorrow
            dayTwo: daytwo,
            dayTwoHi: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[1].temperatureMax),
            dayTwoLo: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[1].temperatureMin),
            dayTwoIcon: iconLooper(iconTomorrowOut),
            // day three
            dayThree: daythree,
            dayThreeHi: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[2].temperatureMax),
            dayThreeLo: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[2].temperatureMin),
            dayThreeIcon: iconLooper(iconDay3Out),
            // day four
            dayFour: dayfour,
            dayFourHi: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[3].temperatureMax),
            dayFourLo: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[3].temperatureMin),
            dayFourIcon: iconLooper(iconDay4Out),
            // day five
            dayFive: dayfive,
            dayFiveHi: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[4].temperatureMax),
            dayFiveLo: Math.round(weather_json.daily.data[4].temperatureMin),
            dayFiveIcon: iconLooper(iconDay5Out)
        }

        let weatherData = {
            weather: weather
        }

        res.render('index', weatherData)
    })

});

app.listen(8000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>weatherApp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">

    <!-- header 
        <div class="header">
            <button class="refresh-btn" onClick="window.location.reload()">Refresh</button>
        </div>
        -->

        <div class="row">
        <!-- icon -->
            <div class="column iconColumn">        
                <img class="currentWeatherIcon" src='<%=weather.currentIcon%>' />
            </div>

        <!-- descriptions -->
            <div class="column description">
            <button class="refresh-btn" onClick="window.location.reload()">Refresh</button>
                <h5><%=weather.currentTemp%>&deg;F  |  <%=weather.summary%></h5> 
                <h5>Feels like <%=weather.currentFeelLike%>&deg; F | humidity <%=weather.currentHumidity%>%</h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h6 class="daySummary"><%=weather.dailySummary%></h6>
    <!-- table -->
            <table>
            <th>Today</th>
            <th><%=weather.dayTwo%></th>
            <th><%=weather.dayThree%></th>
            <th><%=weather.dayFour%></th>
            <th><%=weather.dayFive%></th>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src='<%=weather.todayIcon%>' />
                  <div class="hi-lo"><%=weather.todayHi%>&deg;-<%=weather.todayLo%>&deg;</div>
              </td>
              <td>
              <img src='<%=weather.dayTwoIcon%>' />
                  <div class="hi-lo"><%=weather.dayTwoHi%>&deg;-<%=weather.dayThreeLo%>&deg;</div>
              </td>
              <td>
              <img src='<%=weather.dayThreeIcon%>' />
                  <div class="hi-lo"><%=weather.dayThreeHi%>&deg;-<%=weather.dayThreeLo%>&deg;</div>
              </td>
              <td>
              <img src='<%=weather.dayFourIcon%>' />
                  <div class="hi-lo"><%=weather.dayFourHi%>&deg;-<%=weather.dayFourLo%>&deg;</div>
              </td>
              <td>
              <img src='<%=weather.dayFiveIcon%>' />
                  <div class="hi-lo"><%=weather.dayFiveHi%>&deg;-<%=weather.dayFiveLo%>&deg;</div>
              </td>
        
            </tr>
          </table>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a simple clock using client javascript, it has nothing to do with server rendering. You can simply run javascript code inside your `ejs` file inside `script` tags. Check this simple example which you can find on https://[www.w3schools.com/js/](https://www.w3schools.com/js/):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    </head>
    
    <body onload="startTime()">
    <h3> Here is a simple clock.</h3>
    <div id="clock"></div>
    <script>
    function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML =
      h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }
    // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  
      return i;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you so much for your reply! Would it be best practice to put that into it's own javascript file though, or is this alright to do?

Comment: Glad to help you. Generally it is better practice to put javascript logic and  functions into its own file. If the answer solves your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do DOM manipulations, you have to include JS file to the HTML, like you did with CSS. Change your `<head>` to this

```
<head>
    <title>weatherApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="/js/script.js">
</head>
```

Create `js` directory near `css` and `script.js` file in it, javascript you add there can be executed from your ejs template.